# How to create a dynamic sequence based on Many2one fields?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

How to create a dynamic sequence based on *Many2one* fields, instead of fixed values.

For example, student registration number based on degree, batch and year.
How can I implement this using a sequence in Odoo 10?

Comment: You may update the `prefix` field before get the next sequence number

Comment: @majid Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a dynamic sequence following the next steps. I'd have been more accurate if you had given more details about your code, but I think you'll understand the idea to manage your purpose.

Create a *sequences.xml* file in *data* folder, and add the file to the `__openerp__.py`:

```
<record id="seq_type_student_registration_number" model="ir.sequence.type">
    <field name="name">Student registration number</field>
    <field name="code">student.registration.number</field>
</record>

<record id="seq_student_registration_number" model="ir.sequence">
    <field name="name">Student registration number</field>
    <field name="code">student.registration.number</field>
    <field name="prefix">DEGREE/BATCH/%(y)s</field>
    <field name="padding">3</field>
</record>
```

In your *.py file, inherit from your model to modify its `create` method:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(YourModel, self).create(vals)
    sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code(
        'student.registration.number') or '/'
    sequence = sequence.\
        replace('DEGREE', record.degree_id.name).\
        replace('BATCH', record.batch_id.name)
    record.write({
        'your_field': sequence,
    })
```

Comment: This code creates an error :

 @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @majid that error seems to be in other part of your code, to be sure comment the whole `create` definition I wrote you here and check that the error is still happening.